# Can't copy column name in Pycharm by right click

Tags: python, pycharm

I am using pycharm, when I view my data as dataframe, I should be able to copy the column name of my dataset by right click. But I can't do it now, I don't know what happen and how to fix.

As shown here, I only have a filter here, I remember I can copy column name before...:

[image: As shown here, I only have a filter here, I remember I can copy column name before...]

I restart my PC which doesn't work...